# Possible to limit the number of times a value can be inserted?

Tags: sql

I have a temp table with the following (The table has 1064 records with 25 different RevID. Each RevID is currently listed in the table with a count anywhere from 30-55 times. Each DegreeNo is in the table 4 times and requires a different RevID. The goal is to have each RevID in the table the same amount of times. In this case, each RevID should have a count = 22.

Goal: 1. Assign a RevID to the DegreeNo where the Major is not equal to the short_plan
2. RevID can only be assigned 22 times.

**TempNomTable**

```
**RevID    DegreeNo   Major**
UF1        12345678    SOCIOL
UF3        12345678    SOCIOL
UGK        12345678    SOCIOL
KHS        12345678    SOCIOL
UF25       01234555    DESIGN
UF6        01234555    DESIGN
UF1        01234555    DESIGN
UF3        01234555    DESIGN
```

**#TempR TABLE**

```
**RevID     SHORT_PLAN**
UF1       DENTIST
UF2       VET
UF3       GUESS
UF4       HR
UF5       DESIGN
... 
...
```

### mult_nom TABLE

```
**DegreeNo   Major  comp_id**
 12345678    SOCIOL   2
 01234555    DESIGN   2
```

This is the query that is inserting into the temp table:

```
    WITH Match_NWithR AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    DegreeNo, 
    RTRIM(Major) AS Major,
    COUNT(1) as rowcnt, 
    comp_id
FROM  #mult_nom
GROUP BY  DegreeNo, 
         RTRIM(Major),
         comp_id
)
, rownum_matches AS (
SELECT  m.DegreeNo, 
        m.Major,
        t.Revid,
        m.rowcnt,
        m.comp_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m. DegreeNo order by newid()) AS rownum

       FROM Match_NWithR m
      join #tempR t ON t.short_plan != m.major 
      GROUP BY  m.DegreeNo, m.Major,
      t.RevID, m.rowcnt, m.comp_id
      HAVING COUNT(t.RevID) <= 22
  )

  INSERT INTO #TempNomTable
  SELECT  RevID,  DegreeNo, Major, comp_id   FROM rownum_matches rm 
  WHERE rownum <= rowcnt 
  group by RevID, DegreeNo, Major, comp_id
  HAVING COUNT(RevID) <= 22
```

I have even tried using an update cursor to just update the RevID IF THE COUNT IS > 22 but that is not working either. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER ?

Comment: What does `select max(rownum) from rownum_matches`, return?

Comment: Dan, max(rownum) returns  the value 25

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: PM 77-1, Can you provide an example? Any other ideas??